# Will my AWS storage be wiped after a reboot?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, hosting

I'm hosting a website on a simple Ubuntu 14.04 AWS instance. It works pretty good, but I'm running out of space, so I need to expand the storage space. For this I first want to get comfortable with a pretty basic thing: rebooting/stopping/starting. On any normal linux box I would simply do `sudo reboot`, but on [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html) I read a line saying:

> When you stop an instance, the data on any instance store volumes is erased.

As far as I understand, this has something to do with wether you use EBS or not. The only thing the instance details say about this is the following:

```
EBS-optimized: False
Root device type: ebs
```

But so far I'm kinda confused. Why would the data on the instance be erased? Isn't it a regular linux installation which persists after a reboot? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For on-demand/reserved instances:

No. Stop a instance will not delete the EBS volume.
AWS will delete the EBS when you `terminate` the EC2 instance.

`Instance Store` is a different type of storage: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html

Comment: @rolnald8192 it will only delete if selected `delete on termination` during the launch of the instance.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned that your Root Device is of type **ebs**, so your data will not be wiped after a reboot but will be after termination because by default all ebs volumes got deleted after the termination of instance to which it was attached., But you can also configure not to delete on termination.

Data on ephemeral storage is not persistant.